# Automatic insertion of a colon after 'def', 'if' etc

Tags: python, vim

I recently switched to Vim at the request of a friend after Sublime Text 2 decided it didn't believe a module was installed even though it was...I digress.

I've managed to set up some stuff to make editing Python (currently me only language) easier. However, there's one feature I'm missing from Sublime. It would automatically add a colon to the end of lines which require them (the beginning of function definitions, if statements etc.). This prevented countless annoying errors and I miss it :P

I was wondering whether there was some sort of command I could put in .vimrc to do this.

An example:
If were to type `def`, I would like vim to automatically insert a colon to make it `def :` and place the cursor before the colon ready for me to type my function name.

Cheers and apologies if I'm being stupid in any way.

Comment: If you don't use a plugin make sure you place the rules in a `~/.vim/ftplugin/python.vim`, this will make use of the filetype plugin to ensure you only apply the rules to Python files.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rather than use `imap`s like @CG Mortion's answer suggests, I would strongly advise you to use `iabbr`s for these sorts of small fixes instead.

With an `imap` you would never be able to type "define" in insert mode unless you paused between pressing 'd', 'e', or 'f', or did one of a number of other hacky things to prevent the mapping from happening.  With `iabbr` the abbreviation is only expanded once a non-keyword character is pressed.  `iabbr def def:<left>` works exactly as you'd expect and it doesn't have the drawbacks of `imap`s.

---

As mentioned in other answers, I would also suggest you move on to a snippet engine once you decide that you want something a little more complex.  They are very powerful and can save you loads of time.

Comment: Cheers. Sounds like the way to go. Snippet plugins look great but overkill for now I think, I'll wait until I need them.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at [the old snipmate](https://github.com/msanders/snipmate.vim/), [the new snipmate](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate/) and [ultisnips](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2715). These plugins provide roughly similar "snippet-expansion" mechanisms modeled after TextMate's system.

Answer (score 1):

This [snippet](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/vim/message/16157) doesn't do exactly what you are asking, but it may still be useful to you.

Basically, it puts a semicolon at the end of a line (if the line starts with predefined words, and the colon is not there yet) when you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

```
inoremap <cr> <c-r>=ColonCheck()<cr><cr>

fun! ColonCheck()
  if getline(".") =~ '^\s*\(if\|else\|elif\|while\|for\|try\|except\|finally\|class\|def\)\>.*[^:]\s*$'
    return ":"
  else
    return ""
  endif
endfun
```

Comment: Cheers. Will go with @CGMorton answer I think, but this gives me a list of all the keywords where it applies (something which, embarrassingly, I didn't actually know)

Comment: @Whonut Don't look for short-terms fixed. Using plugins will be benificial on the long term. Don't say we didn't warn you though ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather hacky answer, but you can do a simple mapping like:

```
inoremap def def :<Esc>i
```

which would do exactly what you want.  That is, when you type 'def', it interprets that as 'def :', then escapes back to normal mode (here you could move about a bit), then back to insert.

This works as well:

```
inoremap def def :<Left>
```

The problem, of course is that it will substitute defs whenever they appear, which is not ideal.

Comment: Cheers, works a treat, hacky or not. I'll replicate it for other keywords. I really should learn about mapping etc. :D

Comment: This won't be filetype specific and every time you type something like "definitely" it will replace it too. Could be quite annoying. I think a `inoremap def<Tab> def :<Esc>` may be a better option.

Comment: Then why not use `inoreabbrev def def:<Left>` instead? This doesn't trigger for "definitely".

Comment: @glts I didn't realise it would do that, didn't read to the end of the answer like a twit. Apologies for my idiocy

Answer (score 0):

Simlar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6950427/875064

```
augroup PythonProgramming
   au BufNewFile,BufRead,BufEnter   *.py   iabbr def def:<left>
augroup END
```

Answer (score 0):

I use LunarVim and add to the config this line:

```
lvim.keys.insert_mode[":<Enter>"] = "<Esc>$a:<Enter>"
```